# PITCH and YAW to 2d screen coords?

Tags: c++, math

So i need to somehow convert PITCH and YAW angles pointing at a entity in a 3d world (i also have distance) to 2d screen X and Y positions. Does anyone know how i would go about this?

Comment: There are many ways to do it; you'll have to give us more information.

Answer (score 4):

Example.

Let's assume:
screen size is 1024x768 (`X` = 0..1024, `Y` = 0..768);
horizontal angle of view is 180 grad (`YAW` = -90..90).

Then you can convert `YAW` to `X` this way: `X = k * (YAW + 90)`.

For this example `k` = horiz_screen_size / horiz_angle_of_view = 1024/180.

Then we need to find vertical angle of view: vert_angle_of_view = vert_screen_size / `k` = 768/(1024/180) = 135 grad => `PITCH` = -67.5..67.5.

So, you can convert `PITCH` to `Y` this way: `Y = k * (PITCH + 67.5)`.

---

General formula:

```
X = k * (YAW + 0.5*horiz_angle_of_view)
Y = k * (PITCH + 0.5*vert_angle_of_view)
```

where

```
k = horiz_screen_size / horiz_angle_of_view
vert_angle_of_view = vert_screen_size / k
```

Comment: how to find out Horiz_angle_of_view?

Comment: @pavansubhash "Let's assume: ... horizontal angle of view is 180 grad"

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, I think you would like to know how to convert from spherical co-ordinate system (scalar length, pitch, yaw) to Cartesian co-ordinate system (x, y, z). If yes, then here is the link to refer to: [Spherical coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system).